# deploying docker, nginx and react

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, containers

I completed the application with React.
I want to run it on the docker container and present it to users.
I can access react when I type **http://localhost:8000**, but I can't access react when I type **http://localhost** that is, how do I access the default react application when I type 
http://localhost

I want the default react application to see when the user types http://localhost Can you help me with this?

Dockerfile

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:8 as react-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

# Stage 2 - the production environment
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx-custom.conf

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;
  #charset koi8-r;
  #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  #error_page  404              /404.html;

  # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
  #
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
  #
  #location ~ \.php$ {
  #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
  #}

  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
  #
  #location ~ \.php$ {
  #    root           html;
  #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
  #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
  #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
  #    include        fastcgi_params;
  #}

  # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
  # concurs with nginx's one
  #
  #location ~ /\.ht {
  #    deny  all;
  #}
}
```

Comment: May I ask what resource you are using?  I'm trying to learn exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out a configuration that matches exactly with yours. I have used both of the docker files that you presented and I used a react app as well. Publishing the port 80 when running the command worked for me. This command:

```
docker container run -p 80:80 nginx-react:latest
```

In this case when building the nginx image I named it nginx-react and tag it latest.

If that command does not work for you. Could you share the list of known hosts of your machine that you are using ?. In case you are not sure where to find the lists of hosts on your machine, check [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) link.